trying to connect esp32 to AWS IOT core and there is an error in the sample code
So I am trying to teach myself AWS and my first project is a gate controller powered by an ESP32 micro controller. I am trying to follow the tutorial on amazon but when I do i get an error with the MQTTClient.h. I literally just copy and pasted this straight from the tutorial and it doesn't work. it throws an error stating,
"no matching function for call to 'MQTTClient::MQTTClient()'"
#include "secrets.h"
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "WiFi.h"

// The MQTT topics that this device should publish/subscribe
#define AWS_IOT_PUBLISH_TOPIC   "esp32/pub"
#define AWS_IOT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC "esp32/sub"

WiFiClientSecure net = WiFiClientSecure();
MQTTClient client = MQTTClient(256);

void connectAWS()
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  Serial.println("Connecting to Wi-Fi");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Configure WiFiClientSecure to use the AWS IoT device credentials
  net.setCACert(AWS_CERT_CA);
  net.setCertificate(AWS_CERT_CRT);
  net.setPrivateKey(AWS_CERT_PRIVATE);

  // Connect to the MQTT broker on the AWS endpoint we defined earlier
  client.begin(AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT, 8883, net);

  // Create a message handler
  client.onMessage(messageHandler);

  Serial.print("Connecting to AWS IOT");

  while (!client.connect(THINGNAME)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
  }

  if(!client.connected()){
    Serial.println("AWS IoT Timeout!");
    return;
  }

  // Subscribe to a topic
  client.subscribe(AWS_IOT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC);

  Serial.println("AWS IoT Connected!");
}

void publishMessage()
{
  StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
  doc["time"] = millis();
  doc["sensor_a0"] = analogRead(0);
  char jsonBuffer[512];
  serializeJson(doc, jsonBuffer); // print to client

  client.publish(AWS_IOT_PUBLISH_TOPIC, jsonBuffer);
}

void messageHandler(String &topic, String &payload) {
  Serial.println("incoming: " + topic + " - " + payload);

//  StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
//  deserializeJson(doc, payload);
//  const char* message = doc["message"];
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  connectAWS();
}

void loop() {
  publishMessage();
  client.loop();
  delay(1000);
}

I have tried looking for others who have faced this problem but no one seams to be using this particular library. I have made sure all of the dependencies have been downloaded and updated and I have looked at the MQTTClient.h file and as far as I can tell the function does in fact exist so I don't know where to go from here.

Can you please provide the full output from the compiler? ("throws an error" would generally refer to a runtime error but I'm assuming you are getting this when compiling)
